# What can be extracted from an identical sock pairing problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let me set the scene:

> There are N pairs of indistinguishable socks (only the leftness/rightness can be distinguished). You randomly pair all socks

This may seem like a silly question, but what can be extracted from or asked of this problem? I would like to know what mathematicians could be looking for in a probability question as such. I can work out the probability of having all the socks pairs containing one left and one right sock:
$$ 
\begin{array}{||c||c||c ||}\hline
N & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & ...\\
\hline
-  & 1 & 2/3 & (2/3)*(3/5)& (2/3)*(3/5)*(4/7)&... \\
\hline
\end{array} 
$$
I noticed that the solution of a higher N is the previous one with a multiple. Assuming this pattern continues, I derived the numerator to be N! and the denominator to be (2N-1)!/(2(N-1)!), thus the end formula for all socks to pair-up left-right looks like:
$$\frac{2(N-1)!N!}{(2N-1)!}$$
But after this I don't know what else I can calculate. This reminds me of the solution to [the first secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem), where it is nice to know the probability of the best case, but the ultimate goal is to know expected value ([Robbins' problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins%27_problem)), however I don't know how to calculate this expected value, for me the changing probabilities are too funky :D

Comment: You want the expected number of LR pairs?  That's easy by linearity.  Given a sock, the probability that its mate has opposite parity is $\frac {n-1}{2n}$.  Now just multiply by the number of pairs, $n$.  Remember that Linearity of Expectation holds even if the events are dependent.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say $\frac n{2n-1}$ for the probability.   Multiplying by $n$ then gives $E_n=\frac {n^2}{2n-1}$ so if $n=1$, you get $E_1=\frac 11=1$ as you should.  And $E_2=\frac 43$.  Sanity check:  draw the first sock.  The second has opposite parity with probability $\frac 23$ and the rest is then forced.  Thus you have two LR pairs with probability $\frac 23$ and $0$ otherwise, confirming the result.

Comment: I am not sure your expression $\dfrac{2(N-1)!N!}{(2N-1)!}$ is correct; try $N=1$ and $N=3$.  I suspect it may be $\dfrac{2^{N-1}(N-1)!N!}{(2N-1)!} = \dfrac{2^{N}(N!)^2}{(2N)!} = \dfrac{2^{N}}{{2N \choose N}}$