# Why does the probability of drawing the opposite parity sock remain constant?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Some time ago I [inquired](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743524/what-can-be-extracted-from-an-identical-sock-pairing-problem) about the following sock pairing problem:

> There are N pairs of indistinguishable socks (only the leftness/rightness can be distinguished). You randomly pair all socks

I was looking for the expected value of paired socks and @lulu in the comments said that it is easy with linearity and that, given a sock, the probability that its mate has opposite parity is $\frac{n}{2n-1}$, but I am confused as to why is this always true.

For example, if $n = 3$, then if I first draw two left socks, then the probability that the next two socks will be a pair is $\frac{1}{4}*1 +\frac{3}{4}*\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2} \neq \frac{2}{3}$($\frac{2}{3}$ comes from the formula provided). Is this because if I draw two left socks it is inevitable that I draw two right socks and so I can "skip time" when this has happened and the probability that the next two socks will be a pair is again $\frac{n}{2n-1}$?

Comment: You had posted another similar question yesterday, but it vanished before I could tackle it. What happened ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Sorry about not letting you know, but I found my mistake so I deleted the question. In the case with 3 shoe pairs, it is impossible to get no pairs at all, but in my calculations it had the probability $\frac{1}{5}$... Maybe I shouldn't have deleted the post, since it could be of use to others, but the question was looking at a specific case $n=3$, so I thought it wasn't too general and this mistake wasn't worth highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning information about some of the socks changes the probability of the rest.

Here’s a simpler example to illustrate. If I have a red and black card face down, the prob either card is red is 1/2. After I look at their first one, if it’s red the second is now definitely black. Similarly in your problem, knowing the first two socks gives you information about the rest changing their probabilities.

In your example with $n=2$, there’s $2/3$ that the first two socks match. If they do, then there’s a $1$ probability that the second pair match (different number!). If they don’t, there’s a $0$ chance the second pair match, so the expected amount of time they match if we didn’t look at the first is $2/3\times 1 + 1/3 \times 0=2/3$ which matches if we had just looked at the second pair first. Linearity of expectation means when you’re trying to get the total value you can just ignore these interaction effects between different socks.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it, in my example I gave an extra precondition of one pair not matching, thus the probability of the next one being a pair changed, thanks!